# Why display empty page without variable values in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I need to display my users table data in the `index.blade.php` file, but when I visit the index view it displays an empty page, it does not display the variables data, which I need. (No errors are displayed.)

index.blade.php

```
@if(isset($users))
@foreach($users as $use)
<h1>{{$use->username}}</h1>

@endforeach
@endif
```

UsersController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;    
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Auth;
use App\User;

use App\Http\Requests;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::userr()->get();
        // $users = User::all();

        return view('users.index')->withUser($users);
        //dd($users);
    }    
}
```

User.php Model

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function getAvatarUrl()
    {
        return "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5(strtolower(trim($this->email))) . "?d=mm&s=40";
    }

    public function scopeUserr($query)
    {
        return $query->where('username',Auth::user()->id);        
    }       
}
```

Can You give me some solutions?

Comment: because there's an internal error

Comment: `return $query->where('username',Auth::user()->id); `
So basically your are trying to get all user with the username that match the current user id?

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to check if the data passed to your blade,
and try to use

```
$model = App\Flight::findOrFail(1);

return view('page',compact('var'));
```

check this
http://www.snippetcase.com/snippet/27/Bind+and+Display+data+in+blade+page+for+laravel